# View Group and Count Query

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to create the below query and I'm getting the error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "GROUP"
LINE 5: GROUP BY s.level and e.grade
^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 107

GradeLevel: For each student’s level (i.e. ugrad/grad), group and count the grades of the student’s enrolled courses (You may join the tables, Enroll and Student then group by two columns: level (Students) and grade (Enroll) then count; you can also use Gradebook view). The View must display the following variables: level (Students), grade, Count.

```
CREATE VIEW gradelevel AS
SELECT s.level, e.grade
FROM students s
INNER JOIN enroll e USING (student_id);
GROUP BY s.level and e.grade

SELECT * FROM gradelevel;
```

Comment: Just remove the question mark after `USING (student_id)`, and move it after `GROUP BY s.level and e.grade`. Voting to close this as a typo.

Comment: New error: ERROR:  argument of AND must be type boolean, not type text
LINE 5: GROUP BY s.level and e.grade;
                 ^
SQL state: 42804
Character: 115

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW gradelevel AS (
  SELECT s.level, e.grade, COUNT(*)
  FROM students s
  INNER JOIN enroll e USING (student_id)
  GROUP BY s.level, e.grade
  );

SELECT * FROM gradelevel;
```

Comment: I noticed I missed the count grades. Count the grade of the student's enrolled courses. How can I add the count? Thank you all.

Comment: `SELECT s.level, e.grade, COUNT(*)` in select line